# Is it possible to lose precision while calulating 1/val twice?

Tags: java, double

If I have a `double d;` if I do:

```
d = 1/d;
d = 1/d;
```

Is this possible that I lose precision? In what case for example?

Comment: Why can't you try this?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran Try what? There is no link.

Comment: He means to run the code and see what happens

Comment: For example, if `d` is `0` `:P`

Comment: @Yoda, Why can't write a simple program and see the output?

Comment: @James The stupidest way to check if something is correct. If something works once it does not mean it will work in different conditions.

Comment: @Yoda The simplest test would be `d == 1/(1/d)`

Comment: Even the very first `1/d` can loose precision: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: Unless you're using computer algebra, i.e. maple/matlab ...

Comment: @Yoda If something *fails* once, you have a positive proof of your hypothesis. Therefore expending at least some effort to find such one value is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ofcourse it's possible to loose precision. Floating-point types such as `float` and `double` are not infinitely precise.

```
double d = 123456789.0;

System.out.println(d);
d = 1 / d;
d = 1 / d;
System.out.println(d);
```

output:

```
1.23456789E8
1.2345678899999999E8
```

Comment: For greater effect you could have used some trivially simple number like 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `double` or `float` then yes you may well lose precision.

However, if you use a `Rational` class such as [this one](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/32class/Rational.java.html) you will avoid precision loss.

Answer (score -1):

Because computer systems use a fixed precision to represent numbers, you will find that `d` does not always exactly equal ( `1/(1/d)`), even though this equation is clearly algebraically equal.

Some reading material: [enter link description here](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html)  you may want to search for more.